# Mysql obtain numbers repeat from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

i've got a database similar to the following SqlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f30a65/1/0

I need to obtain the group by but the trouble is that the data are on multiple columns...

Eg result expected:

VALUE - COUNT or Group By

13 - 2

11 - 1

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Group by on which column ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam i think i cannot do a normally group by column by column because the data are mixed, maybe joining every value in a single alias column and then grouping by this temporary column will work

Comment: Use a `UNION ALL` subquery to "unpivot" the table. And please add data and expected result to your question. sqfiddle has too many timeouts.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the result expected was already present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Group By on combine with all column you could use

```
SELECT value, count(value) as count FROM (
    SELECT C1 as value FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C2 as value FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C3 as value FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C4 as value FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C5 as value FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C6 as value FROM TABLE1
) all_col GROUP BY value
```

Comment: Make sense, done this but now i've got two or more repetition of numbers (with their count) based on their column position